# Difference between the System.Array.CopyTo() and System.Array.Clone()

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, .net-2.0

What’s the difference between the `System.Array.CopyTo()` and `System.Array.Clone()`?

Comment: Kind of a dumb interview question. "I don't recall offhand, let me check the documentation..."

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The **[Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx)** method returns a new array (a shallow copy) object containing all the elements in the original array.  The **[CopyTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copyto.aspx)** method copies the elements into another existing array.  Both perform a shallow copy.  A shallow copy means the contents (each array element) contains references to the same object as the elements in the original array.  A deep copy (which neither of these methods performs) would create a new instance of each element's object, resulting in a different, yet identical object.

So the difference are :

```
1- CopyTo require to have a destination array when Clone return a new array.
2- CopyTo let you specify an index (if required) to the destination array.
```

Edit:

Remove the wrong example.

Comment: Your example is wrong. In the first one, `numbersCopy` is just another reference to the array assigned to `numbers`. This is *not* the same as using the `CopyTo()` method. If you use `CopyTo()`, you will get the same results as in your `Clone()` example.

Also, this is C# - `System.out.println` should be `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: This answer, which is **misleading** as other said is a copy-paste from here: http://geekswithblogs.net/dforhan/archive/2005/12/01/61852.aspx

Comment: According GenZiy's example, both of them are shallow copy. A shallow copy of an Array copies only the elements of the Array, whether they are reference types or value types, but it does not copy the objects that the references refer to. The references in the new Array point to the same objects that the references in the original Array point to.
In contrast, a deep copy of an Array copies the elements and everything directly or indirectly referenced by the elements.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins .It is not very clear to me.If both are shallow copy Then what is deep copy.Why CopyTo() is shallow copy.

Comment: @KumarHarsh A shallow copy just copies the _references_ to the objects, not the objects themselves. For example, let's say you had an array `array` with elements `A`, `B`, and `C`. If you did a shallow copy of `array` and modified `A` in that, the change would be seen in both the original and the copy. If you did a deep copy, you would have completely different objects and this wouldn't happen (this is easier to understand if you have a good knowledge of pointers and references vs values in programming).

Comment: In .Net 3.5, Linq's `ToArray()` method provides a much simpler (and _typed_) way of shallow-cloning an array anyway. Since Array is `IENumerable<T>` it works on it.

Comment: Thanks so much, very comprehensive

Answer (score 34):

One other difference not mentioned so far is that

- with `Clone()` the destination array need not exist yet since a new one is created from scratch.
- with `CopyTo()` not only does the destination array need to already exist, it needs to be large enough to hold all the elements in the source array from the index you specify as the destination.

Answer (score 27):

As stated in many other answers both methods perform [shallow copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) of the array. However there are differences and recommendations that have not been addressed yet and that are highlighted in the following lists.

Characteristics of [`System.Array.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx):

- Tests, using .NET 4.0, show that it **is slower than `CopyTo`** probably because it uses [`Object.MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx);
- **Requires casting the result** to the appropriate type;
- The resulting array has the same length as the source.

Characteristics of [`System.Array.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx):

- **Is faster than `Clone`** when copying to array of same type;
- **It calls into [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.constrainedcopy.aspx) inheriting is capabilities**, being the most useful ones:

  - Can box value type elements into reference type elements, for example, copying an `int[]` array into an `object[]`;
  - Can unbox reference type elements into value type elements, for example, copying a `object[]` array of boxed `int` into an `int[]`;
  - Can perform widening conversions on value types, for example, copying a `int[]` into a `long[]`.
  - Can downcast elements, for example, copying a `Stream[]` array into a `MemoryStream[]` (if any element in source array is not convertible to `MemoryStream` an exception is thrown).
- Allows to copy the source to a target array that has a length greater than the source.

Also note, these methods are made available to support [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) and [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx), so if you are dealing with variables of array types you should not use `Clone` or `CopyTo` and instead use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) or [`Array.ConstrainedCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.constrainedcopy.aspx). The constrained copy assures that if the copy operation cannot complete successful then the target array state is not corrupted.

Comment: This is solid info.  So why don't we write a faster, generic version of Clone?  Something like: Ex: public static T[] ExtFastClone<T>(this T[] arr) { if (null == arr) { return null; } T[] arr2 = new T[arr.Length]; arr.CopyTo(arr2, 0); return arr2; }  Or you could do a casting version (to allow int -> long) like: public static TOut[] ExtFastClone<TIn, TOut>(this TIn[] arr)

Comment: For bare shallow cloning on .Net 3.5 or higher, you can just use Linq's `.ToArray()` method. It makes a copy anyway, and it can be executed on any `IEnumerable<>`, including arrays. And unlike `.Clone()`, it's typed, so no casting needed.

Answer (score 23):

Both perform shallow copies as @PatrickDesjardins said (despite the many misled souls who think that `CopyTo` does a deep copy).

However, `CopyTo` allows you to copy one array to a specified index in the destination array, giving it significantly more flexibility.

Answer (score 8):

```
object[] myarray = new object[] { "one", 2, "three", 4, "really big number", 2324573984927361 };

//create shallow copy by CopyTo
//You have to instantiate your new array first
object[] myarray2 = new object[myarray.Length];
//but then you can specify how many members of original array you would like to copy 
myarray.CopyTo(myarray2, 0);

//create shallow copy by Clone
object[] myarray1;
//here you don't need to instantiate array, 
//but all elements of the original array will be copied
myarray1 = myarray.Clone() as object[];

//if not sure that we create a shalow copy lets test it
myarray[0] = 0;
Console.WriteLine(myarray[0]);// print 0
Console.WriteLine(myarray1[0]);//print "one"
Console.WriteLine(myarray2[0]);//print "one"
```

[the source](http://mgznet.com/CopyToVSClone.aspx)

Comment: I guess, shalow copy means only references are copied, not value. So if you are changing value of myarray[0] from "one" to 0 then should not the value of myarray1[0] and myarray[1] also be 0.

Comment: Sorry, but your guess is wrong. Shallow copy is not a copy of references: "The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object." see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Comment: Shallow or deep copy is _irrelevant if the types you put in your array are primitive/immutable_. Strings and integers _always_ produce a new copy when they get put into something else. To test deep copy, put a complex object (like an array) on one of the spots.

Answer (score 2):

Both CopyTo() and Clone() make shallow copy. Clone() method makes a clone of the original array. It returns an exact length array.

On the other hand, CopyTo() copies the elements from the original array to the destination array starting at the specified destination array index. Note that, this adds elements to an already existing array.

The following code will contradict the postings saying that CopyTo() makes a deep copy:

```
public class Test
{
public string s;
}

// Write Main() method and within it call test()

private void test()
{
Test[] array = new Test[1];
array[0] = new Test();
array[0].s = "ORIGINAL";

Test[] copy = new Test[1];
array.CopyTo(copy, 0);

// Next line displays "ORIGINAL"
MessageBox.Show("array[0].s = " + array[0].s);
copy[0].s = "CHANGED";

// Next line displays "CHANGED", showing that
// changing the copy also changes the original.
MessageBox.Show("array[0].s = " + array[0].s);
}
```

Let me explain it a bit. If the elements of the array are of reference types, then the copy (both for Clone() and CopyTo()) will be made upto the first(top) level. But the lower level doesn't get copied. If we need copy of lower level also, we have to do it explicitly. That's why after Cloning or Copying of reference type elements, each element in the Cloned or Copied array refers to the same memory location as referred by the corresponding element in the original array. This clearly indicates that no separate instance is created for lower level. And if it were so then changing the value of any element in the Copied or Cloned array would not have effect in the corresponding element of the original array.

I think that my explanation is exhaustive but I found no other way to make it understandable.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Clone()` would perform technically deep copy, when pass the array of `int` or string to a method as a reference.

For example

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { -11, 12, -42, 0, 1, 90, 68, 6, -9 }; 

SortByAscending(numbers); // Sort the array in ascending order by clone the numbers array to local new array.
SortByDescending(numbers); // Same as Ascending order Clone
```

Even if the methods sort the array of numbers but it wont affect the actual reference passed to the sorting methods.i.e the number array will be in same unsorted initial format in line no 1.

**Note:** The Clone should be done in the sorting methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `Clone()` method don't give reference to the target instance just give you a copy.
the `CopyTo()` method copies the elements into an existing instance.

Both don't give the reference of the target instance and as many members says they give shallow copy (illusion copy) without reference this is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Both are shallow copies. **CopyTo method is not a deep copy.**
Check the following code :

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public string a = "test1";
}

public static void ArrayCopyClone()
{
    TestClass1 tc1 = new TestClass1();
    TestClass1 tc2 = new TestClass1();

    TestClass1[] arrtest1 = { tc1, tc2 };
    TestClass1[] arrtest2 = new TestClass1[arrtest1.Length];
    TestClass1[] arrtest3 = new TestClass1[arrtest1.Length];

    arrtest1.CopyTo(arrtest2, 0);
    arrtest3 = arrtest1.Clone() as TestClass1[];

    Console.WriteLine(arrtest1[0].a);
    Console.WriteLine(arrtest2[0].a);
    Console.WriteLine(arrtest3[0].a);

    arrtest1[0].a = "new";

    Console.WriteLine(arrtest1[0].a);
    Console.WriteLine(arrtest2[0].a);
    Console.WriteLine(arrtest3[0].a);
}

/* Output is 
test1
test1
test1
new
new
new */
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array.Clone** doesn't require a target/destination array to be available when calling the function, whereas **Array.CopyTo** requires a destination array and an index.

Answer (score -2):

`Clone()` is used to copy only  structure of data/array it doesn't copy the actual data.

`CopyTo()` copies the structure as well as actual data.

Answer (score -2):

Please note: There is a difference between using String[] to StringBuilder[].

In String - if you change the String, the other arrays we have copied (by CopyTo or Clone) that points to the same string will not change, but the original String array will point to a new String, however, if we use a StringBuilder in an array, the String pointer will not change, therefore, it will affect all the copies we have made for this array. For instance:

```
public void test()
{
    StringBuilder[] sArrOr = new StringBuilder[1];
    sArrOr[0] = new StringBuilder();
    sArrOr[0].Append("hello");
    StringBuilder[] sArrClone = (StringBuilder[])sArrOr.Clone();
    StringBuilder[] sArrCopyTo = new StringBuilder[1];
    sArrOr.CopyTo(sArrCopyTo,0);
    sArrOr[0].Append(" world");

    Console.WriteLine(sArrOr[0] + " " + sArrClone[0] + " " + sArrCopyTo[0]);
    //Outputs: hello world hello world hello world

    //Same result in int[] as using String[]
    int[] iArrOr = new int[2];
    iArrOr[0] = 0;
    iArrOr[1] = 1;
    int[] iArrCopyTo = new int[2];
    iArrOr.CopyTo(iArrCopyTo,0);
    int[] iArrClone = (int[])iArrOr.Clone();
    iArrOr[0]++;
    Console.WriteLine(iArrOr[0] + " " + iArrClone[0] + " " + iArrCopyTo[0]);
   // Output: 1 0 0
}
```

Comment: This is not related to `CopyTo` vs `Clone`. It's just reference semantics vs value semantics. int is a value type, so you get a new copy every time. StringBuilder has reference semantics, so you are acting on the same copy.

Comment: @nawfal - I know, that was why I wrote 'please note'...
there is a difference of behavior between String, StringBuilder and int, in copyto and clone, and it can be confusin for someone who is not aware of it.