# Array.Sort() sorts original array and not just copy

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

This code snippet is from C# 2010 for Dummies.  What confuses me is that when using the Array.Sort() method, both my copy of the array (sortedNames) and the original array (planets) get sorted, even though it only calls the Sort method on sortedNames.

It doesn't matter which array the second foreach loop references, the output is the same.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The 5 planets closest to the sun, in order: ");
    string[] planets = new string[] { "Mercury","Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter"};
    foreach (string planet in planets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + planet);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nNow listed alphabetically: ");


    string[] sortedNames = planets;
    Array.Sort(sortedNames);

    foreach (string planet in planets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + planet);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sortedNames` and `planets` refer to the same object

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both `sortedNames` and `planets` refer to the same array. Basically both variables point to the same location in memory, so when you call `Array.Sort` on either variable, the changes to the array are reflected by both variables.

Since arrays in C# are *reference types*, both `sortedNames` and `planets` "point" to the same location in memory.

Contrast this with *value types*, which hold data within their own memory allocation, instead of pointing to another location in memory.

If you wanted to keep `planets` intact, you could use create a brand new array, then use `Array.Copy` to fill the new array with the contents of `planets`:

```
/* Create a new array that's the same length as the one "planets" points to */
string[] sortedNames = new string[planets.Length];

/* Copy the elements of `planets` into `sortedNames` */
Array.Copy(planets, sortedNames, planets.Length);

/* Sort the new array instead of `planets` */
Array.Sort(sortedNames);
```

Or, using LINQ you could use `OrderBy` and `ToArray` to create a new, ordered array:

```
string[] sortedNames = planets.OrderBy(planet => planet).ToArray();
```

Some resources that might help with *value types* and *reference types*:

- [Value types and Reference Types (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `Array.Clone` to avoid having to first create a new array. Then sort.

```
string[] sortedNames = (string[]) Array.Clone(planets);
Array.Sort(sortedNames);
```

See also this other discussion [Difference between the System.Array.CopyTo() and System.Array.Clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/198496/6205848)