# Keeping State of an array inside a recursive method

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

Is there an easier way to pass an array through a recursive method than to convert it to a string and re assembling it again inside the method to keep the previous instance of that array for use inside a gametree.

the method only loops till desired depth is reached and bubbles up till all possible game states are mapped.

Example c#:

```
public class Gametree
{
  private char[] mapArr;

  private void execute(char[] map){
    mapArr = map;

    //do stuff to mapArr//

    var child = new Gametree();
    child.execute(mapArr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to copy or clone your array, instead of reference it.

```
child.execute(mapArr.Clone());
```

or

```
char[] secondMap = new char[mapArr.length]
Copy(mapArr, secondMap, mapArr.length);
child.execute(secondMap);
```

Comment: Alternatively Array.Copy and Array.Clone as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198496/difference-between-the-system-array-copyto-and-system-array-clone.

Comment: I did try child.execute(mapArr.toList().toArray()); 
but somewhere along the line it still alters the wrong instance :(

Comment: @Kortgat use Clone or Copy, I'm not 100% sure about the toListtoArray thing.

Comment: Thank you, with some playing around with Array.Copy() I got it to work correctly shaving off more than 30% of processing time :)