# C# Newly copied Array still keep the relation with the source Array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, dictionary

I am facing an annoying issue when I am trying to copy an array. The new array keeps a relation even if it's created by .copy() method. Here is the situation,

Main Class

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] DataCurrentDict = new Dictionary<string, string>[result.Data.Count()];

// 1. Here the DataCurrentDict array is filled with values, having DataCurrentDict[0]["Weight"] = "0.345";
      
ProductData CurrentProductData = new ProductData(DataCurrentDict);

// 2. Here, the CurrentProductData._ProductDataDict[0]["Weight"] = "0.345", GOOD

DataCurrentDict[0]["Weight"] = "1111";

// 3. Here is the problem... After setting a value into DataCurrentDict, the copied array is modified too! So CurrentProductData._ProductDataDict[0]["Weight"] = "1111" ...Why?
```

ProductData Class

```
public class ProductData : IDisposable
{
    private Dictionary<string, string>[] _ProductDataDict;

   //CONSTRUCTOR
   public ProductData(Dictionary<string, string>[] ProductDataDict)
   {
       try
       {
           _ProductDataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>[ProductDataDict.Count()];

           Array.Copy(ProductDataDict, _ProductDataDict, ProductDataDict.Length);
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

Comment: Its hard to know what you are trying to achieve, but you do know  a copy of a reference type aka reference is still the same reference ?

Comment: @00110001, so how to copy/clone content into a new independent array? I thought that .copy() method was for that instead of an assignment. Thanks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198496/difference-between-the-system-array-copyto-and-system-array-clone/198500#198500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an *array* of [*reference type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), copying the *array* of *reference type* gives you the same underlying *reference identity*, it's as simple as that.

You can think of a *reference* is an *address* to something, like a *post-it-note* to something physical in your cupboard, recreating the post-it-note doesn't move the object.

If you want to recreate the reference identity (allocate new memory for your object), aka your dictionarys, there are several solutions.

```
_ProductDataDict = ProductDataDict
   .Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value))
   .ToArray();
```

or (likely more efficient)

```
_ProductDataDict = ProductDataDict
   .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, string>(x))
   .ToArray();
```

They both recreate the `Dictionary`, and both loop through each element and add/hash them to the new dictionary

This is an except of the constructor code of dictionary that takes a dictionary

```
...
Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d = (Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary;
int count = d._count;
Entry[]? entries = d._entries;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (entries![i].next >= -1)
    {
        Add(entries[i].key, entries[i].value);
    }
}
```

This is an except from `ToDictionary`

```
Dictionary<TKey, TElement> d = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>(capacity, comparer);
foreach (TSource element in source)
{
    d.Add(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element));
}
```